# Swipe doesn't display next <div>

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, swipe

I want to use the plugin http://swipejs.com/. Its a simple plugin to swipe list items.
My problem is: The list item can be swiped but it returns immediately to the original place and doesn't take the next list item.

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
              <ul>
                <li style='display:block'><div>1</div></li>
                <li style='display:none'><div>2</div></li>
                <li style='display:none'><div><img src="img/mimik1.jpg"></div></li>
                <li style='display:none'><div>4</div></li>
                <li style='display:none'><div>5</div></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>   
        <script src='js/swipe.js'></script>
<script>
new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
</script>
```

The problem seems to be jquery.mobile.js . Maybe something overlaps?
Any1 got an idea? The div just swipes back after pulling it away.

best regards